# Sum up values based on two dicts with same keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a Python dictionary like `{'user_id': 'user_checkpoint'}`

```
checkpoints_dict= {"id_11": "checkpoint_a", "id_13": "checkpoint_a", "id_15": 
                   "checkpoint_b", "id_22": "checkpoint_c", "id_99": "checkpoint_c", 
                   "id_4": "checkpoint_d", "id_2": None}

>>> checkpoints_dict 
>>> {'id_11': 'checkpoint_a',
     'id_13': 'checkpoint_a',
     'id_15': 'checkpoint_b',
     'id_2': None,
     'id_22': 'checkpoint_c',
     'id_4': 'checkpoint_d',
     'id_99': 'checkpoint_c'}
```

**Note:** a user might have no checkpoint like `id_2`!

I have a second dictionary like `{'user_id': time}`:

```
user_time = {"id_11": 40, "id_13": 95, "id_15": 150, "id_22": 12, 
             "id_4": 154, "id_99": 111 , "id_2": 24, "id_3": 43, "id_5": 65, "id_6": 45}
```

**Note:** Each user_id from `checkpoints_dict` can be found within `user_time`

How do I get the added user_time for each checkpoint within `checkpoints_dict`? Based on the example I would expect sth. like this:

```
result_checkpoint_time = {"checkpoint_a": sum([40, 95]),
                          "checkpoint_b": sum([150]),
                          "checkpoint_c": sum([12, 111]),
                          "checkpoint_d": sum([154])}
```

Since I have no smart idea to approach this I can't show my solutions to this problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use the `user_time` dict on the id you get while iterating over the checkpoint dict:

```
checkpoints_dict = {
    "id_11": "checkpoint_a",
    "id_13": "checkpoint_a",
    "id_15": "checkpoint_b",
    "id_22": "checkpoint_c",
    "id_99": "checkpoint_c",
    "id_4": "checkpoint_d",
    "id_2": None,
}
user_time = {
    "id_11": 40,
    "id_13": 95,
    "id_15": 150,
    "id_22": 12,
    "id_4": 154,
    "id_99": 111,
    "id_2": 24,
    "id_3": 43,
    "id_5": 65,
    "id_6": 45,
}
```

So:

```
result = {}
for id_, checkpoint in checkpoints_dict.items():
    if checkpoint is not None:
        result[checkpoint] = result.get(checkpoint, 0) + user_time[id_]
```